Why does react-native-maps not work when using arrays with "" on Android
I have been having problems getting react-native-maps to work properly on android. The issue is that when I load my array data it works only on IOS. It generates like this :
const locationData = [
    {latitude: "52.4194975", longitude: "-1.5101260"},
    {latitude: "52.403002", longitude: "-1.491740"}
  ];

It is generated from a MYSQL database using PHP.
I display the markers like so:
{locationData.map((data, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: data.latitude,
          longitude: data.longitude
        }}
      />
    ))}

It will work on both IO and Android when I use this :
  const locationData = [
    {latitude: 52.4194975, longitude: -1.5101260},
    {latitude: 52.403002, longitude: -1.491740}
  ];

But if I use this it does not work on Android but its OK on IOS :
  const locationData = [
    {latitude: "52.4194975", longitude: "-1.5101260"},
    {latitude: "52.403002", longitude: "-1.491740"}
  ];

Its obvious it is because of the "" I have tried adding these but they do not work?
latitude: data.latitude,replace('"', '')
latitude: data.latitude,str.replace('"', "")

Is there a workaround or am I missing something? Thanks

Convert a string to a floating point number using parseFloat, something like this:
const locationData = [
  { latitude: "52.4194975", longitude: "-1.5101260" },
  { latitude: "52.403002", longitude: "-1.491740" },
];

const coordinates = locationData.map(c => {
  return {
    latitude: parseFloat(c.latitude),
    longitude: parseFloat(c.longitude),
  };
});

Naturally the best solution is to return numbers already from a backend to avoid any conversion in a client.

Thanks pal, I literally tried most things apart from that! Nice work
